# Is there a way to know if a powerpoint shape is selected by the user?

Tags: powerpoint, office-js, office-js-helpers

I'm creating an addin on powerpoint using office-js and I don't know if there is a method to check if a shape selected by the user ?

I know that in vb.net it looks like this :
 `Dim shape = selection.ShapeRange.Item(1)`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do this in Office.js at this time. It is a good idea. Please consider suggesting it at [Microsoft 365 Developer Platform Ideas](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform).

Comment: It has been a few years, is this still the case?

Comment: I think this can be done now. Try using [getSelectedShapes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/powerpoint/powerpoint.presentation#powerpoint-powerpoint-presentation-getselectedshapes-member(1)). Then check to see if the shape you are interested in is a member of that `ShapeScopedCollection` object.